# Restrict receiving push notification to the same device where it has been pushed from

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am registering for iOS push notification in my app. Push notification is sending to all the devices.

```
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];

[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

I want to restrict receiving push notification where it is sending from. Because, If I send push notification from my A device, and coming to home screen, the same A device is also receiving that push notification. That is not my expected behaviour.

How to restrict receiving push notification to the same device where it has been pushed from?

Comment: You need to target your push to the devices you want to receive the notification - this is controlled by the service that is sending the notification to the APNS server.  Where is the code that actually sends the push?

Comment: It sound's as if you need to manage in your server a table mapping for a deviceToken -> userId. and you'd like to send only one push per user, even if it has many devices.

Comment: OK..There is no way we can restrict on the origin app, where we are pushing messages to server?

Comment: It depends on the API you use to send messages to your server supports any targeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Send the APNS Device Token of Device A to the API/Webservice sending Push Notifications.
 Ask Web service developer to restrict sending Push Notification to APNS Device Token of Device A and send to rest devices.
 And you are done.
```

Comment: OK..There is no way we can restrict on the origin app, where we are pushing messages to server?

Comment: Web service is the origin as it is sending Push Notifications to APNS server. 
You cannot restrict it on client side (iOS Device)